# how do I copy the contents of a file into virtual memory?

Tags: c++, windows, operating-system, virtualalloc

I have a small file, I go over it and count the number of bytes in it:

```
while(fgetc(myFilePtr) != EOF)
{

   numbdrOfBytes++;

}
```

Now I allocate virtual memory of the same size:

```
BYTE* myBuf = (BYTE*)VirtualAlloc(NULL, numbdrOfBytes, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);
```

I now want to copy the content of my file into nyBuf. How do I do it?

Thanks!

Comment: On Linux, there is a nice system call called `mmap` that will do this for you without having to specifically allocate memory. It's possible Windows has something similar.

Comment: to get the file size, your can: `fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END); long size = ftell(fp); rewind(fp);`

Answer (score 3):

In outline:

```
FILE * f = fopen( "myfile", "r" );
fread( myBuf, numberOfBytes, 1, f );
```

this assumes that the buffer is big enough to hold the contents of the file.

Answer (score 3):

Also consider using [memory mapped files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366556%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

int readFile(std::vector<char>& buffer)
{
    std::ifstream       file("Plop");
    if (file)
    {
        /*
         * Get the size of the file
         */
        file.seekg(0,std::ios::end);
        std::streampos          length = file.tellg();
        file.seekg(0,std::ios::beg);

        /*
         * Use a vector as the buffer.
         * It is exception safe and will be tidied up correctly.
         * This constructor creates a buffer of the correct length.
         *
         * Then read the whole file into the buffer.
         */
        buffer.resize(length);
        file.read(&buffer[0],length);
    }
}
```